# Is it possible to see which attributes were matched in a Sphinx resultset?

Tags: sphinx

I have an index which has several different attributes.

`MySQL [(none)]> select * FROM products_index WHERE MATCH('red shoes');`

This returns a bunch of results. Magic. Love Sphinx.

Now, is it possible to see which attribute Sphinx matched on for each of these results?

For example, I have a "colour" field which the "red" would be matching on (potentially), but it could also match on the product name attribute.

Comment: Might need to get your terminology streight. **Attributes** are NOT matched at all by 'MATCH()' - the query matches against **Fields**. The distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

I think `PACKEDFACTORS()` is the only way to do this
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expr-func-packedfactors

It a little cumbersome to use, and adds a bit of overhead to the query, but should work.

(other than post matching, eg using Snippets)